# undefined method `permit' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

while i am creating a comment associated with the posts, i am getting this error::

My comments controller ::

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @comments = Comment.new
    end

    def create 
        @post = Post.find (params[:post_id])    
        @comments = @post.comments.create(params[:comments].permit(:commenter, :body))
        redirect_to post_path(@post)
    end
end
```

// The form for the comments ///

```
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @post.Title %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @post.Text %>
</p>

<%= form_for([@post, @post.comments.build]) do |f| %>

<p>
    <%= f.label :commenter %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :commenter %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :body %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
  </p>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

i am getting error on this line::

```
@comments = @post.comments.create(params[:comments].permit(:commenter, :body))
```

Please point me out where i am wrong..

One edit :: My actual error statement ::

**NoMethodError in CommentsController#create**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax to use strong parameter is

```
params.require(:comments).permit(:commenter, :body)
```

But I think params will contain `comment` not `comments`

So you should use

```
params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body)
```

Answer (score 2):

well, as the error message states, `params[:comments]` is nil.

You should be using `params.require(:comments).permit(:commenter, :body)` so that if `comments` isn't present, it won't go any further.

Also, the actual param being submitted is `comment`, not `comments`. You can verify this by looking at the submitted params in your logs.

Comment: thanx @sevenseacat :: but please tell me how you got this.. i am new to rails..
p.s. - its working now..

Comment: @user3322822 It's covered as part of the getting started Rails guide - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#saving-data-in-the-controller